# Reverse the string using Function and returning the Whole string to main function

Tags: c, string, pointers, reverse

I have Wrote the Following Code Snippet but it is not working. 
Can anyone help me?  Where i am Wrong ??

```
char *xstrrev(char *string)
{
    int len=0,i=0;
    char *reverse;
    while(*string!='\0')
    {
        len++;
        string++;
    }
    len=len-1;
    while(len>=0)
    {
      *reverse=string[len];
       reverse++;
       len--;
    }
    *reverse='\0';
    return reverse; 
}

int main()
{
    char name[10];
    scanf("%s",name);
    printf("%s",xstrrev(name)); 
    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to return whole string in the main function

Comment: `scanf("%s",name);` --> `scanf("%9s",name);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three problems:

[1] `reverse` not pointing to valid memory area.

[2] returning `reverse` will return the last byte address of string `reverse`. so need to store the start of `reverse` and return the start of `reverse`.

[3] `string` is completely parsed while calculating the length, so again, start of original string needs to be saved and used subsequently

```
char *xstrrev(char *string)
{
    char *original_string = string;
    int len=0,i=0;
    //[1] char *reverse;
    while(*string!='\0')
    {
        len++;
        string++;
    }

    //[3] till here "string" is completely parsed, so it points to past the end.

    char *reverse = (char*)malloc(len + 1);
    char *reverse_to_be_returned = reverse;
    len=len-1;
    while(len>=0)
    {
        //[3] *reverse=string[len];
        *reverse = original_string[len]; 
        reverse++;
        len--;
    }
    *reverse='\0';
    //[2] return reverse; 
    return reverse_to_be_returned;
}
```

Comment: Free the returned string after using it.

Comment: `It is not working` is not a useful error description. Please describe _what_ is going wrong and _how_.

Comment: @Gerhardh: see recently added point [3] due to which it did not worked.

Comment: @KunalVerma: Please note memory of (len + 1) needs to be `malloc`ed in order to accommodate ``\0`` character.

Comment: @sameerkn I knew that thing but I am wondering why just a simple thing didn't strikes In my brain

Answer (score 2):

The problem starts (and ends) with

```
  *reverse=string[len];
```

where `reverse` is not initialized. This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to initialize `reverse` to make it point to a *valid* memory location before you can dereference the pointer.

*Since you are expecting to _return_ the new _string_ from your function and use it in the caller, you should use memory allocator functions, like [`malloc()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) to allocate memory and initialize the `reverse` with the returned pointer, after the success check of the `malloc()` call. You also need to take care of `free()`-ing the allocated memory , once you're done using it.*

After that, as per your logic, you're doing `reverse++;` and in the end, you're returning `reverse`, so think of the exact value which is getting returned. You're returning a pointer to the *end* of the string, not a pointer to the *start* of it. You need to keep a copy of the actual start of `reverse` and return that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate space for `char *reverse` to point to. This can be done with [`malloc`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) or [`strdup`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup).

Basically:

> `malloc()`allocates requested memory on the heap, and returns a `void*` pointer in the end.

You also need to check the return pointer of any call to `malloc()`, as sometimes it can return `NULL` if something wrong happens.

You also need to [`free`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_free.htm) this requested memory at the end, just to be safe.

Additionally, since you are returning a pointer, you need to make sure it points at the start of the string, instead of the end.

Your code can look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NAMESTRLEN 10

char *xstrrev(char *string);

int
main(void) {
    char name[NAMESTRLEN+1];
    char *result;

    printf("Enter string: ");
    scanf("%10s", name);

    result = xstrrev(name);
    printf("Reversed string = %s\n", result);

    free(result);

    return 0;
}

char
*xstrrev(char *string) {
    char *result;
    size_t slen, count = 0;
    int i;

    slen = strlen(string);

    result = malloc(slen+1); /* +1 for nullbyte */
    if (!result) {
        printf("Cannot allocate space for string.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = slen-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        result[count++] = string[i];
    }
    result[count] = '\0';

    return result;
}
```

Comment: @KunalVerma, no worries :), upvote my answer if you found it helpful.